# Identical dimensions for train and test matrices in text analysis?

Tags: python, machine-learning

Suppose I have a dataframe with different rows of text, and I want to cluster those rows to find out underlying themes in the data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"id_num": np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 50, size = 10), "text": ["hello these are words i would like to cluster", "hello i would like to go home", "home i would like to go please thank you", "thank you please apple banana", "orange banana apple fruit corn", "orange orange orange banana banana banana banana", "can you take me home i have had enough of this place", "i am bored can we go home", "i would like to leave now to go home", "apple apple banana"])
```

I will first separate this dataframe into `train` and `test`:

```
>>> from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
>>> train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.40)
>>> train, test = train["text"], test["text"]
```

Then start the clustering process:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

>>> train_X = vectorizer.fit_transform(train)
>>> test_X = vectorizer.fit_transform(test)

>>> model = KMeans(n_clusters = 2)

>>> model.fit(train_X)

>>> model.predict(test_X)

ValueError: Incorrect number of features. Got 22 features, expected 18.
```

Of course, if you run this code on your own machine, you might get different results. Perhapsthe number of features might even be aligned. But in most cases, the dimensions of `train_X` and `test_X` will not match up.

Has anyone else dealt with this issue? I suppose one approach to make the dimensions equal would be to employ some sort of dimensionality reduction by taking only the features (read: words) that are present in both `train` and `test`.  The other solution, which would make larger matrices, would be to fill in zeros in both matrices where a given document doesn't have the word from the other corpus.

Is there another way I should be approaching this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, I found several StackOverflow answers to this same question: [Python vectorization for classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806383/python-vectorization-for-classification) and [Scikit learn - fit_transform on the test set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21998008/scikit-learn-fit-transform-on-the-test-set).

In short, I needed to change

```
train_X = vectorizer.fit_transform(train)
test_X = vectorizer.fit_transform(test)
```

to

```
train_X = vectorizer.fit_transform(train)
test_X = vectorizer.transform(test)
```

Using `transform` instead of `fit_transform` preserves the vocabulary created from `fit_transform` in the previous line, and ensures identical columns for these matrices.

Comment: since it is a duplicate, instead of giving an answer, just mark a question as duplicate.